# Rewritten implementation of quadratic equation formula

Tags: c, homework, floating-point

I just started learning the C programming language at the university, and today we got a new assignment there is about Refinement of a C software there is designed to find the roots of the general quadratic equation. We got an old C software that we have to rewrite with functions instead of using the Whole code inside main. We have to split the functions into 3 where is about

- Calculation of the discriminant.
- Calculation of the first root.
- Calculation of other root.

The old code:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <math.h>
>
> /* Prints roots of the quadratic equation a * x*x + b * x + c = 0 */
> void solveQuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c){
>   double discriminant, root1, root2;
>
>   discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
>
>   if (discriminant < 0)
>     printf("No roots\n");
>   else if (discriminant == 0){
>     root1 = -b/(2*a);
>     printf("One root: %f\n", root1);
>   }
>   else {
>     root1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
>     root2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
>     printf("Two roots: %f and %f\n", root1, root2);
>   }
>
> }   
>
> int main(void) {
>   double a = 1.0, b = -8.0, c = 15.0,
>          d = 2.0, e =  8.0, f =  2.0,
>          g, h, i;
>
>   /* First call - coefficents are values of variables */
>   solveQuadraticEquation(a, b, c);  
>
>   /* Second call - coefficents are values of expressions */
>   solveQuadraticEquation(d - 1, -e, 7 * f + 1); 
>
>   /* Third call - coefficents are entered by user outside 
> solveQuadraticEquation */
>   printf("Enter coeficients a, b, and c: ");
>   scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &g, &h, &i);
>   solveQuadraticEquation(g, h, i);  
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

My Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double discriminant(double a, double b, double c);
double root1(double a, double b, double c);
double root2(double a, double b, double c);

/* Prints roots of the quadratic equation a * x*x + b * x + c = 0 */
void solveQuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c){

  if (discriminant(a, b, c) < 0)
    printf("No roots\n");
  else if (discriminant(a, b, c) == 0){
    printf("One root: %f\n", root1(a, b, c));
  }
  else {
    printf("Two roots: %f and %f\n", root1(a, b, c), root2(a, b, c));
  }

}

int main(void) {
  double a = 1.0, b = -8.0, c = 15.0,
         d = 2.0, e =  8.0, f =  2.0,
         g, h, i;

  /* First call - coefficents are values of variables */
  solveQuadraticEquation(a, b, c);

  /* Second call - coefficents are values of expressions */
  solveQuadraticEquation(d - 1, -e, 7 * f + 1);

  /* Third call - coefficents are entered by user outside 
solveQuadraticEquation */
  printf("Enter coeficients a, b, and c: ");
  scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &g, &h, &i);
  solveQuadraticEquation(g, h, i);

  return 0;
}

double discriminant(double a, double b, double c){
    return b * b - 4 * a * c;
}

double root1(double a, double b, double c){
  return (-b + sqrt(discriminant(a, b, c)))/(2*a);
}

double root2(double a, double b, double c){
  return (-b - sqrt(discriminant(a, b, c)))/(2*a);
}
```

I have already made a well-working solution, but I was wondering if I could make it even better, so if I have done something wrong or weird, please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from re-computing `discriminant()`, a reasonable quadratic implementation.

---

When assessing the quality of floating-point computations, use `"%e"` rather than `"%f"`.  I recommend using `"%e"` with enough precision too.  Like `"%.17e"`, or [use one of the `DECIMAL_DIG` family of constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359).

---

Precision improvement when `b*b` near `discriminant`:

When `|b|` is about `sqrt(discriminant)`, the computation of `root1` or `root2` will cancel many digits.  To avoid this, consider that `a*root1*root2 = c`

```
// calculate root1 and root2 together.
if (b < 0) {
  root1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
  root2 = c/(root1*a);
} else {
  root2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
  root1 = c/(root2*a);
}
```

Try `a=1.0, b = -1e24-1, c = 1e24.`  Roots should be `1e24, 1` as here.  OP's approach  results in `1e24, 0`, *total* loss of precision.  Keep in mind, FP has overall logarithmic precision, not linear.

When `b*b` and `discriminant` greatly differ, this approach is not significantly weaker than OP's original.

Precision improvements are possible with `b * b - 4 * a * c`, yet tend to impact performance more.

---

Advanced concern:

`root1()`, `root2()` is on thin ice at it relies on a non-negative result from `discriminant()`.

C is sneaky in that FP code is allowed to use higher than needed precision selectively.  See `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

With OP's code, this certainly will not happen as is, yet with a subtle change of in-lining `b * b - 4 * a * c;` instead of an explicit function call, may yield the following:

A test of `b * b - 4 * a * c < 0` may be false yet the later `(-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c))` may attempt a square root of a negative value due to different optimizations.

Solution: Use the same result rather than re-compute `discriminant`.  Do not rely on "same looking code" to generate the exact same FP result especially when near 0.0.

This also eliminates the wasteful re-computation of `discriminant()`.

---

Check spelling on "coefficents": I'd expect "coefficients".

---

To meet OP's goal to split the functions into 3: `discriminant, first root, other root` consider:

```
double discriminant(double a, double b, double c);
double first_root(double discriminant, double a, double b);
double other_root(double root1, double a, double c);

...
doubled = discriminant(a, b, c);
if (d < 0) ...
else if (d == 0) ....
else {
  double root1 = first_root(discriminant, a, b);
  double root2 = other_root(root1, a, c);
  ...
}
```

Comment: For the accuracy would you recommend using something like`b*b * math.sqrt(1+(4*a*c/ (b*b))*4*a*c/ (b*b)))`

Comment: @OscarSmith Close: `b*b-4*a*c` loses much precision when `4*a*c` is about `b*b`.  IMO, loss of precision in `a*c` is unrecoverable, yet `b` can be salvaged a bit.  Instead `t = a*c*4; if (t <= 0) d = b*b - t; else u = sqrt(-t); d = (b-u)*(b+u);`.  Further, instead of `d = b*b - t; dsr = sqrt(d)` -->  `dsr = hypot(b, sqrt(-t));`  Some of these ideas do help yet for ever more niche cases.  The speedier idea is to use `long double`.  Of course then how to improve precision for a `long double` quadratic?

Answer (score 5):

You are computing the discriminant too many times.

For example,  in the `root1`, `root2` and the condition in the solveQuadraticEquation function.

Just store the discriminant a variable and pass it as an argument to `root1` and `root2`.

That way you can also avoid to passe `c` as an argument to `root1` and `root2`.

Also, but this is only to avoid repetition of code, you can transfer some common behavior of your functions into smaller ones or compute them incrementally.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will definitely look into this!